# Android Studio: Run/Debug Configurations unable to create application

Tags: java, android

Hi I'm having a problem in creating a configuration in Android. Last week this one is still working and i can able to run it but opening it today the configuration is unknown already. I didn't do anything for the codes last week I just run it.

Here's the screenshot of my Run/Debug Configurations.

[image]

I tried creating new application run/debug configuration but running it display

1. an icon with cross
2. also display "Error Running SyncActivity: No JDK specified"

I'm using Android Studio and I'm new in this project android.
Thank you in advance
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the JDK for your project and/or modules.

Open the project settings (File->Project settings...).

Most of the time you just need to set the project sdk (to your java sdk) and configure the modules to use the project sdk.
Probably one of those settings is missing.

Comment: Hi Akshay, thanks for your reply but how can I setup the project sdk and configure it to the modules?

Comment: Go to

File -> project Structure into Project Structure
Left -> SDK Location
SDK location select Android SDK location (old version use Press +, add another sdk)

Comment: thank you but how will i know what project sdk should i add?

Comment: Click the add another sdk there you will find it